# cloud google appengine can't set Resources

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

This is driving me crazy...
The next button is missing, so I can NOT change the app engine resources.
Can not set the Language nor environment.
If I click do it later, then I'm back at: "Your App Engine application has been created" get started, then back here again.
I tried in Chrome, Brave and Firefox same thing. Tried to create a new app, same thing.
Please help me!

[image]

Comment: Is this happening when you tried to create an App Engine App via the console? If so, you can just ignore it and create your App on your dev machine. When you deploy your app via ```gcloud app deploy```, you will have a valid app with the correct runtime

Comment: Yes, it's via the console. So I just ignore the problem ? it's weird though no ? I keep getting some error when I deploy like : ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/kaniko-project/, and I was wondering if it might be because I didn't set the app Engine Language correctly.

Comment: My bad. I should rephrase - I believe what I do is create App Engine projects on the console without specifying the resources (like language). Then when I deploy my app (with same name as the app engine project), the language comes from the ```app.yaml``` file.

Comment: You can follow this sample [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/create-app#before-you-begin) to deploy the app via console.

Comment: Google cloud console is buggy, and when you ask for help Google requires you to sign up for paid support to get help with their own bugs. :(